# Angular accordion and popover overlay

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ accordion and popover inside accordion.
But Popover and accordion creates overlay and popover block displays only inside accordion.
[image]

Html code:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group is-open="element.hide" is-disabled="lock">
        <accordion-heading>
            <a href="" ng-click="element.hide = false"><i class="icon-chevron-right" ng-hide="element.hide"></i></a>
            <a href="" ng-click="element.hide = true"><i class="icon-chevron-down" ng-show="element.hide"></i></a>
            <i ng-show="element.description" popover="{{element.description}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="icon-info-sign"></i> 
        </accordion-heading>
        //inner eccordion HTML
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you can provide a plunkr. But i feel like "popover-append-to-body" might solve your problem.

```
<i ng-show="element.description" popover="{{element.description}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-body="true" class="icon-info-sign"></i>
```